# Generics - define Map<MyClassA<?>, MyClassB<?>> ensuring both ? are the same?

Tags: java, generics

I have a line of code:

```
private final Map<MyClassA<?>, MyClassB<?>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Is there any way to define that map in a way that would tell the compiler that the ? in each case must be the same class?

Something like this?

```
private final <T> Map<MyClassA<T>, MyClassB<T>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

... which is not legal syntax?

It's just a self-learning question at this point.

FWIW, I want to add a method

```
public <T> MyClassB<T> getForA(MyClassA<T> a) {
    return this.myMap.get(a);
}
```

But I get a compile error unless I can define `myMap` to insist that both the key and the value wrap the same type.

Comment: You would need to define the generic type at the class level.

Comment: You can always add in a concrete type. Otherwise you need to provide a generic parameter.

Comment: I cannot define the generic type at the class level.  Each map entry can have a different T.  It's just that for each entry, the key and the value wrap the same type.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak This is not something you can express with the syntax. This is also not how `Map`s are designed to work. All calls to `get(...)` on one map should returnt he same type. This pretty much sounds like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you give us some insight as to why you need to enforce this constraint?

Comment: @turing85 yeah, when something is hard to do, it's usually a good indication that you shouldn't be doing it.  I can figure out an alternate solution myself -- I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a way to do it this way (e.g., some cool syntax I didn't know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already figured out, you can't do that if key and value are different for different entries:

```
map.put(new MyClassA<Foo>(), new MyClassB<Foo>());
map.put(new MyClassA<Bar>(), new MyClassB<Bar>());
```

(I've taken this requirement from [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58225226/generics-define-mapmyclassa-myclassb-ensuring-both-are-the-same#comment102825676_58225278))

What you can do is to write some helper methods, which enforce this constraint:

```
public <T> void put(MyClassA<T> key, MyClass<B> value) {
    // Maybe check at runtime if the constraint is not validated?
    map.put(key, value);
}

public <T> MyClassB<T> get(MyClassA<T> key) {
    // This will produce an unchecked warning.
    return (T) map.get(key);
}
```

As long as you only access the map through such helper methods (and don't use raw types), the constraint on the map will not be violated, which allows you to write type safe code.

The only part that is not typesafe are those helper methods, and that's where you have to be careful.

Comment: In certain places it is not uncommon to have `Map<Class<?>, Object>`, where each value is an instance of the Class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar if you introduce one static inner class for the type you need.  For example:

```
public class DoubleGenericTest<T> {

   public static class MapHolder<Z> {
      private final Map<MyClassA<Z>, MyClassB<Z>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
   }

   private final MapHolder<String> stringMap = new MapHolder<>();
   private final MapHolder<Integer> integerMap = new MapHolder<>();


}

class MyClassA<X> {}
class MyClassB<Y> {}
```

This gives you the class you need to hang the type parameter onto.  Maybe not ideal in every situation but it's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Again, it is not the case that every entry in the map wraps the same type "Z".  It is that the key and the value of each entry must map the same type.  So this doesn't work for me either.

Comment: So you're saying they're the same, but you don't know what that type is?  Could you give a more concrete example?  I'm also suspecting some sort of XY problem here.